# DateTime formatting returns strange results

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
```

and i then print it. Here are the results:

Localhost:

```
date: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

On server:

```
date: 1-1-0001 0:00:00
```

The correct way is the one on localhost. How to fix this and why is this happening? It's the same code.

Comment: Because of different regional setting on different machines

Comment: it might be your server has different time and timezone

Comment: For "strange" read "correct results according to the documented behaviour".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of different regional setting on different machines. To have date time output in the same format you ahve to specify format string explciitly:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Also as John recommeded in comments below if you want having date time output in the same format on different machines despite local regional settings you can use [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) format provider:

```
date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with
>   the English language but not with any country/region

MSDN:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Note that custom format specifiers are usually best combined with the invariant culture, whereas standard format specifiers are appropriate when specifying a "user" culture (e.g. US.)

Comment: Interesting, I know that logging should be done using `InvariantCulture`, so it is better specifying `InvariantCulture` for `dateTime.ToString()` as well?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to display something to a user, you should probably use one of the standard formats in their user culture. If you're providing data to be understood by another computer, then the invariant culture is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the invariant culture to display your date, if you are not too concerned about the format so long as it is always the same.

```
date.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the date the way you've shown it there, you could use:

```
date.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Or when using a format string:

```
string.Format("date: {0:M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", date);
```